# Knockoutjs 1.3 beta: valueUpdate doesn't work when you paste a value via mouse

Tags: knockout.js

In ko 1.3 beta when you Cut or Paste a filed's value via the context menu then the binding does not trigger an update to the View Model. I've tryied with all valueUpdate options.

This works perfectly in other versions. Is there a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

There was a fix from 1.2.1 that did not make it into the original 1.3 beta.  The fix was to make sure that the `value` binding always handles the change event of the input along with any other events that are passed by `valueUpdate`.

If you take the latest version from: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/tree/master/build/output it has the necessary fix.

This will make it so the value will at least update when you leave the field in any way.

However, if you really want it to update immediately after the paste, you can do something like:

```
<input data-bind="value: name, valueUpdate: ['afterkeydown', 'afterpaste']" />
```

You could certainly just bind to `afterpaste`, but this shows how you can actually pass an array of events to `valueUpdate`.  Accepting an array of events was part of the fix that was missing as well.

Comment: It looks like 'afterpaste' never made it into KO 2.0?

Comment: The fix that made it in was to always response to the change event. Currently, if you want to handle `afterpaste` (or `input` or both) you would have to include it in an array passed to the `valueUpdate` additional binding.

Comment: Is there a certain browser or situation that you are seeing it not work?

Comment: Safari was not showing me any changes after pasting, until I leave the element. No biggie, as in this case, input was actually more useful. I think I can just leave in `input` `change` `afterpaste`.

Answer (score 1):

Whilst the `afterpaste` event appears to have never made it into Knockout, there is another event, which some browsers support: `input`.

```
<input data-bind="value: name, valueUpdate: 'input'">
```

This works well in recent WebKit browsers, YMMV.